# How to Construct a GeoPoint in Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

Currently trying to construct a GeoPoint to run a query in Firebase Functions, but am getting errors:

```
const lesserGeopoint = new functions.firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(box.swCorner.latitude, box.swCorner.longitude);
const greaterGeopoint = new functions.firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(box.neCorner.latitude, box.neCorner.longitude);
```

Gives the error: Cannot read property 'firestore' of undefined

```
const lesserGeopoint = new GeoPoint(box.swCorner.latitude, box.swCorner.longitude);
const greaterGeopoint = new GeoPoint(box.neCorner.latitude, box.neCorner.longitude);
```

Gives the error: GeoPoint is not defined

When I try to include

```
import { GeoPoint } from '@google-cloud/firestore';
```

I recieve an error on deploy:

Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Answer (score 6):

Geopoint was accessible through admin:

```
  const lesserGeopoint = new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(box.swCorner.latitude, box.swCorner.longitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

GeoFirestore GeoPoints can be constructed using:

```
let myGeoPoint = new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(37.785326, -122.405696)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Your answer adds very little to the original question and the answers already given.

Comment: I included my answer because the two answers above didn't work for me. My solution did work.

Comment: @YEG what npm packgage do you use to access new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint()?